# Repairing Windows installed two versions, how do I delete the corrupt one?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, repair-install

While repairing Windows XP, it has setup another version of XP on my computer. So on every reboot, I have to select one Windows XP out of the two presented.

Out of two, one is corrupt and not in use. How do I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888023) knowledge base article from Microsoft outlines the steps.

> 1. Start the Windows operating system that you want to keep.
> 2. To determine the Windows folder that you want to keep, click Start, click Run, type %windir%, and then click OK.
> 3. In Windows Explorer, find the Windows folder that you want to remove.
> 4. Right-click the Windows folder that you want to remove, Delete. Confirm.
> 5. Start, right-click My Computer, Properties.
> 6. Advanced tab, Startup and Recovery, Settings. The Startup and Recovery dialog box appears.
> 7. Under System startup, click Edit to modify the Boot.ini file.

```
  The Boot.ini file opens in Notepad and looks similar to the following:
  [boot loader]
  timeout=30
  default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
  [operating systems]
  multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" 
  /fastdetect
  multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS.0="Microsoft Windows XP Home" 
  /fastdetect
```

> 8. On the File menu in Notepad, click Save As, and then save a backup
>      copy of the Boot.ini file that is
>      named Boot.old. Exit.
> 9. In the Startup and Recovery dialog box, under System startup,
>      click Edit to reopen the Boot.ini
>      file.
> 10. In the [boot loader] section of the Boot.ini file, identify and then
>       delete the line of text for the
>       Windows operating system that you want
>       to remove.
> 11. Save, exit and restart.